# How to determine if numpy.vectorize() is needed?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to determine at runtime if a function requires numpy.vectorize() to behave as expected?

For background, I ask this because I'm using Numpy in a program to calculate phase diagrams from thermodynamic functions available in the literature (CALPHAD-based).  For a given temperature, one evaluates the free energy functions and determines the common tangent curves touching concave-up (second derivative > 0) to define composition ranges of phase coexistence. For this, it was nice to directly define the second derivative function.  All was going well with real free energy functions (not hard to get derivatives of) until I tried to test with a simple parabolic free enrgy, which has a constant second derivative.  This blew up my algorithm since I had not expected the numpy broadcasting to look inside the function and decide it did not need to broadcast.

The difficulty comes down to this behavior:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
   return(x*x)
def g(x):
   return(3.0)
def h(x):
   return(0*x+3.0)
def i(x):
   return(x-x+3.0)

x = np.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 5)
```

Running in IPython 3.3.2 results in these outputs:

> > > f(x) ->
> > >       array([  1.,   4.,   9.,  16.,  25.]) -- what I expected
> > >
> > > g(x) -> 
> > >       3.0 (note only 1 element, and a float, not ndarray) -- not naively expected
> > >
> > > h(x) -> 
> > >       array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]) -- OK, fooled the broadcasting by having x do something
> > >
> > > i(x) ->
> > >       array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]) -- Same as h(x) but avoiding the multiply but with roundoff issues

Now I could use

```
gv = np.vectorize(g)
```

and get

> > > gv(x) -> array([ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]) -- expected behavior

If my program is to (eventually) accept arbitrary user-entered free energy functions this will cause problems unless all users understand numpy internal broadcasting magics.
Or, I could reflexively np.vectorize everything to prevent this.  The problem is the cost if the function will "just work" in numpy.

That is, using %timeit in IPython,

```
h(x) -> 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.45 µs per loop
```

If I vectorize h(x) needlessly (i.e. hv = np.vectorize(h)), I get

```
hv(x) -> 10000 loops, best of 3: 43.2 µs per loop
```

So, needlessly vectorizing is a huge penalty (40 microseconds for 5 function evals).

I guess I could to an initial test on the return of a function evaluating on a small ndarray to see if the return type is array or float, and then define a new function if it is float, like:

```
def gv(x):
   return(g(x)+0.0*x)
```

That just seems like a horrible kludge.

So - is there a better way to 'fool' numpy into efficiently broadcasting in this case?

Comment: You could check the shape of the value returned by `g(x)`, and broadcast it if needed. It's not unusual for `numpy` (and MATLAB) functions to massage the inputs to put them into an optimal shape for calculation, and then further reshape the outputs to match the input shapes.  For example look at the internals of `np.vectorize`.

Comment: why do you want to use numpy.vectorize? i assume after that you want to do f(x)+g(x) or so? but that will work as well when f(x) returns a numpy.ndarray, and g(x) returns a float.

Comment: In general, I don't want to use vectorize().  The issue arises because y=f(x) returns an ndarray if x is an ndarray, but y = g(x) returns one single float value, not an array of len(x).  Thus, if trying to write a library to process functions, you might end up with, well, unusual results when you don't get the expected array back.  numpy.vectorize() is just the kludge to get it to work.

Comment: This is just a thought, but how about writing a decorator to check the outputs of your energy function - and have it reshape to the input array if needed (i.e. if a scalar, resize `x`'s shape).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem shown. If you want a new array:

```
def g(x):
    return np.ones_like(x)*3
```

or if you want to set all elements in an array to 3 in place:

```
def g(x):
    x[:] = 3
```

Note there is no return statement here as you are simply updating array `x` so that all elements are 3.

The issue with `def g(x): return(3)` as shown is there is no reference to numpy inside the function. You state for *any* given input return 3. Stating `x=3` will run into similar issues as you are updating the pointer `x` to point to `3` instead of the numpy array. While the statement `x[:]=3` accesses an internal function known as a view from the `numpy.ndarray` class instead of the usual use of the `=` statement that simply updates a pointer.

Comment: I like this since it avoids some of my other kludge options.  I'll dive into the numpy code if needed, but am still fuzzy on why numpy isn't broadcasting the return value of g() to the input ndarray.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonCuster I have updated the answer some. I think your issue comes from a misunderstanding of how python works rather then the numpy side.

Comment: I appreciate your gentle comment! I had built up a mental model based on f(x) just working.  But, yes, with some model readustments I can see that, if nothing in the function indicates that numpy be involved in the type determination (and thus any broadcasting based on type/size issues), that python itself happily returns the single float that seems to be requested.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you could wrap the user-provided functions to make sure the output shape is correct. For example:

```
def wrap_user_function(func, x):
   out = func(x)
   if np.isscalar(out):
     return np.zeros_like(x) + out
   return out
```

This only handles the scalar output case specially, but it should at least take care of your `g(x)` issue, without imposing much of a performance hit.